Hot reload doesnt work when i use Module federation using Craco
const path = require('path')
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require('@craco/craco')
const packages = []
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, arg) => {
      const { isFound, match } = getLoader(
        webpackConfig,
        loaderByName('babel-loader'),
      )
      if (isFound) {
        const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include)
          ? match.loader.include
          : [match.loader.include]

        match.loader.include = include.concat(packages)
      }

      webpackConfig.output = {
        ...webpackConfig.output,
        publicPath:
          process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL ||
          `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/`,
      }
      webpackConfig.resolve = {
        ...webpackConfig.resolve,
        fallback: {
          crypto: false,
        },
      }

      webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'MyCode',
          filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './MyCodeApp': './src/routes/main',
          },
        }),
      )

      return webpackConfig
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

I am using craco and react and this is my craco.config.js when I make changes in my code hot reload doesn't work However, if I comment out the exposes section in the ModuleFederationPlugin configuration, hot reload works as expected.
What is the solution to enable hot reload while keeping the exposes section?
